# rspec - stub included methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, include

I need to stub a helper method that's included inside a controller. Yes it's bad practice but for now that's what what i have to live with.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
```

Say application_helper has a method `:foo` that's included inside the controller.
I've tried stubbing like:

1. `controller.stub(:foo)`
2. `@helper = Object.new.extend ApplicationHelper; @helper.stub(:foo)`

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with this before:

```
@controller.stub(:foo)
```

Notice the `@` before the `controller`.